# PHP retrieve data from table row and store to variable

Tags: php, mysql

i guess the questions says it all. The result of my query results into a row which will match the condition. I want to get each data from each table column and put into a variable.

```
$getinfo = "select 
                   user_firstname, 
                   user_middlename, 
                   user_lastname 
              from tempuserinfo 
             where user_email ='$ead' 
               and activation_code='$eac'";

$query = mysql_query($getinfo, $db);
if(!$query) {
    echo'something went wrong.';
} else {
    //put them into variables
    $firstname = mysql_fetch_object($query, 'user_firstname');
    $middlename = mysql_fetch_object($query, 'user_middlename');
    $lastname = mysql_fetch_object($query, 'user_lastname');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting multiple results, you can loop through them like this:

```
$getinfo = "select user_firstname, user_middlename, user_lastname from tempuserinfo where user_email ='$ead' and activation_code='$eac'";
$query = mysql_query($getinfo, $db);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
    $lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
}
```

If you are only getting one row back (make sure you add a LIMIT to your SQL statement), then you can use something like this:

```
$getinfo = "select user_firstname, user_middlename, user_lastname from tempuserinfo where user_email ='$ead' and activation_code='$eac'";
$query = mysql_query($getinfo, $db);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
$lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_*  function are deprecated. In documentation its recommended like in latest versions of PHP they are going to use mysqli_* or PDO.

Below are the script using mysqli for your question:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root_user", "root_password", "database");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$getinfo = "select 
                   user_firstname, 
                   user_middlename, 
                   user_lastname 
              from tempuserinfo 
             where user_email ='$ead' 
               and activation_code='$eac'";



if ($result = $mysqli->query($getinfo)) {    
     while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $firstname = $row->user_firstname;
        $middlename = $row->user_middlename;
        $lastname =$row->user_lastname;
    }
    $result->close();
}
else
{
   echo'something went wrong.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

an example with mysqli, mysql as this deprecated

```
$sql = "select user_firstname, user_middlename, user_lastname from tempuserinfo where user_email ='$ead' and activation_code='$eac'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $user_firstname = $rs['user_firstname'];
    $user_middlename = $rs['user_middlename'];
    $user_lastname = $rs['user_lastname'];
}
```

if you want to have all fields in order to consult them later, add them to an array

```
$i=0;
while($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $data[$i] = array('user_firstname'=>$rs['user_firstname'], 'user_middlename'=>$rs['user_middlename'], 'user_lastname'=> $rs['user_lastname']);

    $i++;
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$firstname = $result->user_firstname;
$middlename = $result->user_middlename;
$lastname = $result->user_lastname;
```

**BUT:**
Use MySQLi or PDO sintead mysql module is deprecated already

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'dbuser';
    $password = 'dbpass';
    
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    try {
      $sth = $dbh->prepare("select user_firstname, user_middlename, user_lastname from tempuserinfo where user_email = ? and activation_code=?");
      $sth->execute(array($ead,$eac));
      $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
      $user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
      $user_middlename = $row['user_middlename'];
      $user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Database operation failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Really, do learn to use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), because it is as easy as using mysql_*, but much safer and better.